# Is there a programmatic way to get access to the current selections of a Slicer?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using a slicer in a report Sheet that I'm building and would like to add the contents of the slicer's selection to the report output. There doesn't appear to be anyway to get to it from the GUI, so I'm hoping I can manage it using apps script. I don't see anything in the API reference about slicers, so  I have a hunch the answer today is no, but maybe someone can surprise me!

Thanks!

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Here's a super simple version that shows off what I'm trying to do. In cell A3 I'd like to bring in the list of choices from the slicer. Without it you can't see what selections have been made without re-opening the slicer. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zo3Sy-5zMFTiU5JEggsXN7At0DlaFtuzZ0quQIo1G9Y/edit#gid=997038140

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, the slicer cannot be retrieved and controlled by a script, because the values cannot be retrieved by Sheets API. I think that such functions might be added in the future. I apologize that your issue was not resolved soon.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, that's what I had figured as well; hopefully this already on someone's radar at the big G. I know slicers were just introduced in the last several weeks, so it's not too surprising that they aren't fully baked yet.